# Missing HyperLink Text in iTextSharp PDF

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am trying to export a grid view to a pdf report using iTextSharp. The gridView includes one HyperLink Field which is not showing in the pdf file.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped" Style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: medium" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="903px" DataKeyNames="ID" >
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Start_Date" HeaderText="Start_Date" SortExpression="Start_Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="End_Date" HeaderText="End_Date" SortExpression="End_Date" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Agenda_Title" DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Views/Portal/ViewAgenda.aspx?ID={0}" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-Width="150px"></asp:HyperLinkField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Start_Time" HeaderText="Start_Time" SortExpression="Start_Time" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="End_Time" HeaderText="End_Time" SortExpression="End_Time" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have attached a SQLDatasource to the gridview control which uses a Select Command to get the populate the gridview.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ArtistManagementSystem %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Start Date] AS Start_Date, [End Date] AS End_Date, Title AS Agenda_Title, [Start Time] AS Start_Time, [End Time] AS End_Time, ID FROM Agenda WHERE ([Event ID] = @Event_ID) ORDER BY Start_Date, Start_Time">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Event_ID" QueryStringField="evtID" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

And then a Button to export the gridview to PDF.

```
<asp:Button ID="exportToPDF" Text="Export To PDF" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" ForeColor="#ffffff" BackColor="#b52e31" OnClick="exportToPDF_Click" />
```

This is the code behind:

```
protected void exportToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count);

        foreach (TableCell headerCell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            Font font = new Font();
            font.Color = new BaseColor(GridView1.HeaderStyle.ForeColor);

            PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerCell.Text, font));
            pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor);
            pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
        }

        foreach(GridViewRow gridviewRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach(TableCell tblCell in gridviewRow.Cells)
            {
                Font font = new Font();
                font.Color = new BaseColor(GridView1.RowStyle.ForeColor);

                PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tblCell.Text));
                pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor);
                pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
            }
        }

        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDocument.Open();
        pdfDocument.Add(pdfTable);
        pdfDocument.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Agenda.pdf");
        Response.Write(pdfDocument);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

This is how I am seeing the report:
[image]

The title column always appears empty.

Kindly help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tblCell.Text));
```

for the link column, I don't think you will get `tblCell.Text` populated. Instead, you need to check for `tblCell` child controls by examining [tblCell.Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell(v=vs.110).aspx) property. By iterating `tblCell.Controls` you should be able to find your link control there, maybe like `tblCell.Controls[0]` .

Just stop in the debugger over that line for the Title column and see what `tblCell.Controls` contain. Then cast the appropriate link control to the actual link control type shown in debugger and access the link control's Text property.

HTH